# Running a process from python module multiprocessing and kivy locks without answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, spyder

This simple program doesn't execute correctly, locking in the message "Read message" after press the button. I think I'm not wrong in multiprocessing code because I can run this code without kivy with no problems, but if I simply add same import modules from kivy, the process stops returning any value. In fact my tests show the process even start to run.

I did a very simple code to show the problem. You can simply copy and run. When I press the button test the program locks immediately and the main thread does't receive the message from process.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event

kv = '''
<InterfaceView>:
    Button:
        text: 'teste'
        on_press: root.do_process()
'''

def pprosess(message, q, stop):    
    q.put(message)    
    stop.wait()

Builder.load_string(kv)

class InterfaceView(BoxLayout):

    def do_process(self):
        q = Queue()
        stop = Event()

        p = Process(target=pprosess, args=('any message', q, stop))  
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

        print('Read message')      
        print('message: ', q.get())

        stop.set()      
        p.join()

        print('Process closed')

class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return InterfaceView()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleApp().run()
```

The code below executes very well the same thing without kivy, believe me, or not. Here you can observe the correct terminal output.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event

def pprosess(message, q, stop):    
    q.put(message)    
    stop.wait()

def main():
    q = Queue()
    stop = Event()

    p = Process(target=pprosess, args=('any message', q, stop))  
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()

    print('Read message')      
    print('message: ', q.get())

    stop.set()      
    p.join()

    print('Process closed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm very frustrated struggling with this for days long. Please, somebody help me.

Comment: Tried your code with python 2.7.13 kivy 1.10 on win7 x64 and it works OK. I can't see any v3 specific code that will prevent it from running.

Comment: Hi @embryo, thanks for test my code. In your test, you say works ok because the main thread received the message "any message" visualized in the terminal? Or because you've seen the kivy button "test"? My problem is because the message doesn't arrive in the main thread. Again, thanks for helping me.

Comment: It worked because it printed the same messages as the non-kivy script..

Comment: Thanks @embryo, I already solved my problem. Look at my answer if you´re curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem, in fact, was with Spyder Development Environment and/or some of its components.

I was using the current IPython console to run my code, when I change to execute in an **external terminal** the problem was solved.

Thanks @embryo and specially @ikolim for helping. Their tests and suggestion lead me to the problem.

So, if you use **Spyder Development Environment**, attention to bad interaction effects between **IPython console**, python multiprocessing module and kivy.

All codes I posted are correct with no problems.

Answer (score 4):

The `stop.wait()` event is causing the problem. It is equivalent to time.sleep(). Remove `stop` should fix the problem.

[Programming Guide » Events and Properties » Main loop](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html)

> In Kivy applications, you have to avoid long/infinite loops or sleeping.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event

kv = '''
<InterfaceView>:
    Button:
        text: 'teste'
        on_press: root.do_process()
'''


def pprosess(message, q):
    q.put(message)


Builder.load_string(kv)


class InterfaceView(BoxLayout):

    def do_process(self):
        q = Queue()

        p = Process(target=pprosess, args=('any message', q))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

        print('Read message')
        print('message: ', q.get())

        p.join()

        print('Process closed')


class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return InterfaceView()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: Hi @ikolim, thanks for taking time to help. I test your suggestion and still doesn't work for me. In your test, did the main thread receive the message "any message" visualized in the terminal? Or are you saying solved because you've seen the kivy button "test"? My problem is because the message doesn't arrive in the main thread, nevertheless when I press the button the application locks. Again, thanks for try helping me. I will try to improve my question.

Comment: @Randolfo: In my example, after I pressed the button the main thread received and printed the message, ***any message*** as shown in the print screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ikolim, sorry I lost the terminal in your print screen, my fault! Now I think I can work in environment problems because the exact same code locks here. Could you send me your environment configuration? Mine is Anaconda 3 5.0.1 64, python 3.6.4, kivy 1.10.0, win10 x64. I tried on another computer with win7 x64 too.  Best Regards.

Comment: Anaconda3-5.1.0, conda 4.5.2, Python 3.6.5, Kivy 1.10.0, Xubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver).